# What is the hardware that has this serial number?

Tags: hardware, headphones

I have what appears to be an ear piece of some sort. Not sure. Serial number is 12731HOSXAP Model No A1221. What is it?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Apple iPhone Bluetooth headset. 
[Link to Apple site](http://www.apple.com/support/headset/)

Answer (score 2):

This is the **iPhone Bluetooth Headset**, discontinued March 2009.

The support page for the hardware is:

- http://www.apple.com/uk/support/headset/